# Total number of used containers

Tags: docker

Is it possible to get the number of containers used since the start of the system?
Command `docker info` shows only existing ones and doesn't count removed containers.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with vanilla Docker - what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Trying to collect statistics for JupyterHub-based application.